# Shorthand to compare multiple columns against same condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does a shorthand exist that allows you to compare multiple columns against the same condition in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Date1] BETWEEN x AND y
OR [Date2] BETWEEN x AND y
OR [Date3] BETWEEN x and y
OR [Date4] BETWEEN x and y
```

It's not the end of the world to copy and paste this condition and replace [Date x] with each column, but it sure isn't fun.

Comment: The only way would be to create a string and execute the string with sp_executesql. This is probably not a good solution due to performance, but I don't think there's another way.

Comment: When I see this I can't help but think that the design is not well normalized. There really shouldn't be all that many datetime columns in most tables.

Comment: Maybe you could look into doing something with an UNPIVOT.

Comment: @SeanLange While I don't have the power to change the database structure (just an analyst at a company), I would love to hear opinions on a better structure for my own knowledge. The table I'm working with is a "Status" table for mortgage loans where there's a single row for each loan and multiple columns for each status containing the respective date the loan was placed into that status. What would be a better structure for this relationship?

Comment: Well, a table with loanId, Status and CreateDate should be a good start...

Comment: Instead of columns for each status those should be rows. I would do something like have a "parent" row for the loan and then another table for LoanStatus and each row would have the LoanID, StatusID and StatusDate or something close to that. It allows multiple times a given status could be used etc and provides a more accurate picture of the history. Poorly normalized data structures are definitely going to be an uphill battle from the sound of the design you are working with here.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write the query like this (in SQL Server 2008 or later):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (Date1),(Date2),(Date3),(Date4)) v (TheDate)
    WHERE TheDate BETWEEN x AND y
)
```

However, I don't see any benefits of doing so (in terms of peformance or readability).

Of course, things would be different if you need to write `Date1=x OR Date2=x OR Date3=x OR Date4=x`, because in this case you can simply write `x IN (Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cross apply` and `values`, but the result is even more cumbersome than the code you have right now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  MIN([Date]) As MinDate, 
            MAX([Date]) As MaxDate
    FROM (VALUES ([Date1]), ([Date2]), ([Date3]), ([Date4])) VALS([Date])
)
WHERE MinDate <= y
AND MaxDate >= x
AND x <= y
```

With that being said, I agree with Sean Lange's comment - Seems like the table structure is ill-designed and all these dates values should be in a different table, referenced by this table with a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Your query does not return the same results as the original query. At a first glance, you could say it is fixable by replacing < with <= and > with >=. However, even after that it won't return the same results if x>y (it should return nothing in this case).

Comment: if `x > y` then `mindate < y and maxdate > x` will return false. However you are correct about the inclusiveness of `between...and`.  A good read: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: How about when x=3, y=2, Date1=1 and Date2=Date3=Date4=4?

Comment: @RazvanSocol correct. Also easily fixable by adding `and x <= y`, though...